# Merging Attributes in Apache Nifi after a ExtractText (using Regex)

Tags: apache-nifi

After using the Nifi ExtractText processor to extract matches from the flowfile-content using regex (using multiple capturing mode), you are supplied with a series of numerically ascending attributes. E.G. date, date.0, date.1, date.2, ... representing multiple captures throughout the text.

What I want is a single attribute ${dates}, that contains each of the entries captured. Can anybody help?

(Nifi v1.5.0)

Answer (score 2):

Use update attribute processor
add new property with expression language

**dates:**

```
${allMatchingAttributes("date.*"):join(",")}
```

this expression which join all date,date.0,date.1,date.2 and add dates attribute to the flowfile.

For more reference:-

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#join

Answer (score 0):

The `date.0` attribute is what you are likely interested in.

For example, I used a `GenerateFlowFile` processor to create flowfiles which contain the text `This is a message generated at ${now():format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z')}` which will result in content like `This is a message generated at 2018/02/21 09:25:16.832 -0800.`

I then used an `ExtractText` processor with a new attribute called `date` with the following regex: `(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) .?\d{4}` You can see this has two capture groups -- one for the year/month/day portion and one for the hour/minute/second/millis portion.

After running the `ExtractText`, this is the result. You can see that the individual capture groups are in `date.1` and `date.2`, but `date.0` contains the entire regular expression match.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Wed Feb 21 09:25:16 PST 2018'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Wed Feb 21 09:25:16 PST 2018'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '62'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'date'
    Value: '2018/02/21'
Key: 'date.0'
    Value: '2018/02/21 09:25:16.832 -0800'
Key: 'date.1'
    Value: '2018/02/21'
Key: 'date.2'
    Value: '09:25:16.832'
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '813454866687188'
Key: 'firstName'
    Value: 'Andy'
Key: 'fullName'
    Value: ' '
Key: 'lastName'
    Value: 'LoPresto'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '9e5de17c-2d62-401e-ad13-d49adf5fdd85'
--------------------------------------------------
This is a message generated at 2018/02/21 09:25:16.832 -0800.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get those values by using [getDelimitedField](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield) expression language.

If you want capture your flowfile content, use ExtractText processor in that itself create new attribute with following regex.

```
dates:(.*)
```

if you have content like below

```
1,Hi,23,001
```

It going to be store in attribute named **dates** and you can use it in flow by **${dates}**

In that it self if you want get those values use below expression.

Use update attribute, to capture those values like below.

```
ID :${dates:getDelimitedField(1)}
Name:${dates:getDelimitedField(2)}
Age:${dates:getDelimitedField(3)}
```

You may use that in flow as usual like`${ID},${Name},${Age}`

Hope this really helpful for you.